# Advise on creating relationship in mysql with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, relationship

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this as I am novice and very confused

I want to able to assign customer to user (1:M relationship) but I cant figure how to do this in mysql. What I would like to do is in the customer table add the multiple id's of the user and then create a table where you can assign a new customer to a certain user or search how many customer a particular user has etc...

I have been looking at creating relationship but I keep getting error in phpmyadmin

Can anyone advise how to do this properly in the db please

Thanks for all your help

Comment: You need to define "customer" a little more. Most people would equate a  customer and user object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your problem is creating the relationship in PHPMyAdmin, i should recommend you the following:

- Create the user table with the user_id as PK.
- Create the customer table adding the user_id column and defining it as an INDEX.
- Go to Customer table structure, and click on "View Relations".
- On the user_id field, choose the User_table.user_id.

This way, an user can have zero or many customers and a customer will always belong to a single user.

Comment: Thank you all mt. Schneiders suggestion has worked a treat thanks all!!

Answer (score 1):

What about the following

```
> +Users
> -id
> -email
> -full_name
> 
> 
> +Customers
> -id
> -user_id
> -name
> -phone
```

So `user_id` will contain the `id` of the user which this customer belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ofir Baruch. But the problem I can see with this is how do I add multiple user id's to customer -user_id?

Comment: In this case you should use @Randy 's solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
user
------
user_id
other_stuff

customer
--------
customer_id
other_stuff


user_customer
-------------
user_id
customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks Randy for your advise this is how I planned to do this but then couldn't figure out how to add multiple id's in user_customer? Because it's an int value right?

Comment: each new pair of id's becomes a new row.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in trying [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) It's a visual MySQL database modelling tool created and supported by Oracle/MySQL guys. Not only does it tidy away messy SQL code (but you should still understand what's going on) but seeing your database model visually is often a big help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jonathan I will try that now thanks